# How could I link woocommerce product to an API or Link Address of my store?

Tags: php, woocommerce, product

I need to update my website WooCommerce products with the list of products I have in my physical store via my own in-store warehouse application api (API code is an Address link that works very well with POSTMAN or INSOMNIA).
I put and tested various codes and functions in the "function.php" file in the WordPress dashboard of my site, but unfortunately I did not get the desired result.
I just put this code that still does not work for me ?!

```
  // Product Information
$sku = 'product_id';
$regular_price = 'SellRate';
$sale_price = 'SellRate';
$quantity = 'InventoryQuantity';
$url = 'http://server ip:port/api/pdd/ID='.$sku;
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_product', 'sync_on_product_save', 10, 1 );
function sync_on_product_save( $product_id ) {
     $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
     // do something with this product
        // Send Request To API
$request = wp_remote_get($url, array(
    'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8'),
    'timeout' => 120,
    'body' => array(),
    'method' => 'GET',
                            ));
        // Get Body Of Request
$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($request);
$array = json_decode($body, true);
        $limit = 200;
    // getting all products
    $products_ids = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'        => 'product', 
        'numberposts'      => $limit,
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'fields'           => 'ids',
        'meta_query'       => array( array(
            'key'     => '_sync_updated',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ) )
    ) );
    // Loop through product Ids
 // Search Product By SKU
$product_id = wc_get_product_id_by_sku($sku);
if ($product_id > 0) {
    // Get Product By ID in WooCommerce
    $product = new WC_Product($product_id);

    // Set product stock quantity
    $product->set_stock_quantity($quantity);
    if ($quantity == 0) {
        $product->set_stock_status('outofstock');
        $product->set_manage_stock(false);
    } else {
        $product->set_stock_status('instock');
        $product->set_manage_stock(true);
    }
        // Set Product Price
    if ($regular_price == $sale_price) {
        $product->set_price($regular_price);
    } else {
        $product->set_regular_price($regular_price);
        $product->set_sale_price($sale_price);
    }
    // Save Product
   $product->save();
}
}
```

Can anyone tell me what to do?

Best regards
Amir.

Comment: When making such integration features you must carefully monitor on each step, do a lot of var_dumps, logs, but best solution is to follow exection with xdebug.

Comment: You did not mention what does not working here. Did you get valid response from server? Did you get some error?
You parsing body of response but never use these values.